# Multiple Pushpin and UI Lag

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing

I am currently disaply over 500 pushpins on my bing map using the below code. Loading of these pushpins is causing a serious lag on the UI, so I was wondering if it is possible to load these incrementally based on the users position, but still use this code?

I have seen other examples using bindings and obseravable collections, but I would like to find a solution for the below code if possible.

```
    foreach (var root in Transitresults) 
    {  
       var pin = new Pushpin
         {
             Location = new GeoCoordinate
                 { 
                    Latitude = root.Lat,
                    Longitude = root.Lon
                 },
              Background = accentBrush,
             Content = root.Name,
             Tag = root,
                  }; 

BusStopLayer.AddChild(pin, pin.Location);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this post, It's a good tutorial on only showing the pins that are actually in view:

[Awkward Coder: How many pins can Bing Maps handle in a WP7 app](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-many-pins-can-bing-maps-handle-in.html)

Comment: Nice one, displaying based on BoundingRectangle is an interesting idea. That combined with the trickle works quite well. Cheers.